Go to a specific item in LazyColumn with index using Paging3 on initial load
I am building a social media app that has a profile page. On it, the user can browse their posts from a vertical grid list. Each post has an id(UUID), authorId(UUID) and an image. When the user clicks on a specific post, a callback function is invoked.
In ProfileScreen:
@Composable
fun PersonalProfileScreen(
    viewModel: PersonalProfileViewModel,
    navController: NavHostController,
    snackbarHostState: SnackbarHostState
) {
    val state = viewModel.state.collectAsStateWithLifecycle()

    val postsLazyPagingItems = state.value
        .userProfileSimplePostsFlow.collectAsLazyPagingItems()

    LazyVerticalGrid(columns = GridCells.Fixed(3)) {
        items(
            count = postsLazyPagingItems.itemCount,
            key = postsLazyPagingItems.itemKey { it.id },
        ) { index ->
            postsLazyPagingItems[index]?.let {
                SimplePostItem(
                    imageBitmap = it.image,
                    onClicked = {
                        navController.navigate(PostsScreenRoute(index, it.authorId))
                    }
                )
            }
        }
    }
}

Clicking on a post triggers a navigation to a PostsScreen which gets the index and authorId of the clicked post as parameters. From there I invoke a method in the PostsViewModel, which starts the loading of posts for the new posts screen.
PostsScreen:
@Composable
fun PostsScreen(
    startItemIndex: Int,
    authorId: String,
    viewModel: PostsViewModel
) {

    val lazyListState = rememberLazyListState()

    val postsLazyPagingItems = viewModel.postsState
        .collectAsStateWithLifecycle().value
        .collectAsLazyPagingItems()

    LaunchedEffect(key1 = true) {
        viewModel.initPosts(startItemIndex, authorId)
    }

    LazyColumn(state = lazyListState) {
            items(
                count = postsLazyPagingItems.itemCount,
                key = postsLazyPagingItems.itemKey { it.id },
                contentType = postsLazyPagingItems.itemContentType { it }
            ) { index ->
                postsLazyPagingItems[index]?.let {
                    PostItem(
                        postModel = it,
                        snackbarHost = snackbarHost,
                        navController = navController
                    )
                } ?: Text(text = "loading")
            }
        }
}

PostsViewModel:
@HiltViewModel
class PostsViewModel @Inject constructor(
    private val postsUseCases: PostsUseCases,
    private val postUseCases: PostUseCases,
    private val database: AppDatabase,
    private val apiService: PostApiService
) : ViewModel() {

    private val _postsState = MutableStateFlow(emptyFlow<PagingData<PostModel>>())
    val postsState: StateFlow<Flow<PagingData<PostModel>>> = _postsState.asStateFlow()

    @OptIn(ExperimentalPagingApi::class)
    fun initPosts(startItemIndex: Int, authorId: String) {
        viewModelScope.launch {
            //clearing cache after each navigation to PostsScreen,
            //before loading any posts
            database.postDao.clearAll()
            postsState.value =
                Pager(
                    initialKey = startItemIndex,
                    config = PagingConfig(
                        pageSize = POSTS_PAGE_SIZE,
                        prefetchDistance = POSTS_PAGE_SIZE,
                        maxSize = 3 * POSTS_PAGE_SIZE,
                        jumpThreshold = 3,
                        enablePlaceholders = true
                    ),
                    remoteMediator = PostRemoteMediator(
                        appDb = database,
                        apiService = apiService,
                        authorId = authorId,
                        startItemIndex = startItemIndex
                    ),
                    pagingSourceFactory = { database.postDao.pagingSource() }
                ).flow.map { pagingData ->
                    pagingData.map { it.asPost().asPostModel(postUseCases) }
                }.cachedIn(viewModelScope)
        }
    }
}

PostRemoteMediator:
@OptIn(ExperimentalPagingApi::class)
class PostRemoteMediator(
    private val appDb: AppDatabase,
    private val apiService: PostApiService,
    private val authorId: String,
    private val startItemIndex: Int
) : RemoteMediator<Int, PostEntity>() {

    override suspend fun load(
        loadType: LoadType,
        state: PagingState<Int, PostEntity>
    ): MediatorResult {
        val loadKey: Int = when (loadType) {
            LoadType.REFRESH -> startItemIndex / POSTS_PAGE_SIZE
            LoadType.PREPEND -> {
                var firstLoadedPage: Int
                withContext(Dispatchers.IO) {
                    firstLoadedPage = appDb.postDao.getFirst().page
                }
                if (firstLoadedPage == 0) {
                    return MediatorResult.Success(endOfPaginationReached = true)
                } else firstLoadedPage - 1
            }

            LoadType.APPEND -> {
                withContext(Dispatchers.IO) {
                    appDb.postDao.getLast().page + 1
                }
            }
        }

        // I use a wrapper class for API responses. This returns list of Posts
        // which can be retrieved via content if the network response code is less than 300,
        // else error is true
        val apiResponse = apiService.getPosts(authorId, loadKey)

        if (!apiResponse.isError) {
            if (apiResponse.content!!.isEmpty()) {
                return MediatorResult.Success(endOfPaginationReached = true)
            }
            val postEntities = apiResponse.content.map {
                val entity = it.asPostEntity()
                entity.page = loadKey
                entity
            }
            appDb.postDao.upsertAll(postEntities)

            return MediatorResult.Success(endOfPaginationReached = false)
        }
        return MediatorResult.Error(ApiResponseException(apiResponse.httpStatusCode))
    }
}

Now, the problem is that I want to set the scroll position to the post item, that the user clicked in the ProfileScreen right after navigating to PostsScreen(during composition). However, I can't just requestScrollToItem(startItemIndex) as the Posts are being initially loaded and the requested index may still not be available. Also, prepending pushes items at the beginning of the list and the scroll position follows the newly prepended items.
Example scenario:
We have POSTS_PAGE_SIZE = 4 and startItemIndex = 10
During composition, posts list size is 0, so I can't request scroll to any index. After refresh has completed, the list size is 4 and the item of interest, that we want to keep to the top of the viewport has an index of 2(because the first loaded page during the refresh stage would be startItemIndex / POSTS_PAGE_SIZE, as defined in PostRemoteMediator and page counting begins from 0) so it would be startItemIndex % POSTS_PAGE_SIZE = 2.
However, after the first prepend, the list size is 8(not taking append into consideration), therefore the item of interest has now an index of POSTS_PAGE_SIZE + startItemIndex % POSTS_PAGE_SIZE = 6
After the second prepend, the item of interest has an index of 2 * POSTS_PAGE_SIZE + startItemIndex % POSTS_PAGE_SIZE = 10
I've tried calculating the index offset by observing loadState changes in LaunchedEffect composables in order to call lazyListState.requestScrollToItem(), but any of the variants I've tried seemed to be reliable, if working at all. In addition to that, if I request scroll to item with an index small enough to trigger prepending, prepending will continue up until the very first page and the first visible item will change, because the scroll state is kept static, but each prepend "pushes" the items of the new page. Maybe I can wait until all prepends and appends complete and somehow calculate the required scroll offset, but I can't reliably figure out when the initial prepend and append operations complete. There are no resources regarding this issue and I can't come up with a working solution. I have never used Paging3 before so maybe I am overcomplicating things needlessly.
Also, I can't reuse the posts from ProfileScreen as the post image is smaller size(used like a thumbnail).
EDIT:
As @Leviathan suggested, I was able to find the requested item by it's id.
 //in PostsScreen
 // Note: this works only if placeholders are enabled

    val hasBeenInit = remember { mutableStateOf(false) }
    val shouldRequestInitialScroll = remember { mutableStateOf(true) }
    
    LaunchedEffect(key1 = postsLazyPagingItems.loadState.isIdle) {
        if (postsLazyPagingItems.loadState.isIdle) {
            //during composition, the load state will be idle, we should request scroll until
            //the actual initial loading operations complete and loadState becomes idle again.
            if (!hasBeenInit.value) {
                hasBeenInit.value = true
                return@LaunchedEffect
            } else if (shouldRequestInitialScroll.value) {
                shouldRequestInitialScroll.value = false
            }
        }
    }

    LaunchedEffect(key1 = postsLazyPagingItems.itemCount) {
        // Keep scrolling to the requested item until initial loading completes.
        // This would solve the problem of prepending up until the first page
        // by ultimately making scroll state's index > the prefetch distance
        if (shouldRequestInitialScroll.value) {
            var isFound = false
            for ((index, item) in postsLazyPagingItems.itemSnapshotList.withIndex()) {
                item?.let {
                    if (it.id.value == startItemId) {
                        lazyListState.requestScrollToItem(index)
                        isFound = true
                    }
                }
                if (isFound) break
            }
        }
    }

This resolves the first issue of finding the requested item with the drawback of waiting to load all initial pages which results in not showing the correct item until postsLazyPagingItems gets initialized but I can live with that(I can overlay LazyColumn with a Box with progress indictor until shouldRequestInitialScroll == true).
However, if the user starts scrolling to top and prepending gets triggered I face an issue, similar to the initialization one. When a new page gets prepended, the first visible item, before prepending, gets sent below the viewport because the scroll state does not get changed, but items list does(prepended items displace the ones before prepending), so the first visible item is not the one, before prepending took place.
In order to mitigate this issue, I've tried to capture the last visible item id before prepending happening and after prepending completes scroll to this item with approach similar to the initialization problem. This would not result in a smooth scroll up experience but at least will not confuse the user. I was unable to and my suspicion is that placeholder height, being different from the regular items confuses the scroll state somehow. Or it could just be a limitation of the Paging3 library?

Can you please [edit] your post an reduce your code to a [mre]? Also please make it more clear when you want to perform the scroll to what position at which point in time.

You seem to pass the post's index of the PersonalProfileScreen's grid to PostsScreen. Why don't you pass the id instead? In PostsScreen you could then loop over postsLazyPagingItems to find the index of the item of that id and then scroll to that index.

@Leviathan Ooof, I was so focused on getting the correct index that I completely overlooked this possibility. In my case it is possible as the entities from the backend belong to the same table so the ids would match for both screens. I've managed to come up with a solution by observing loadStates in LaunchedEffects and search by id. However, when the user scrolls up and prepending takes place, the first visible item gets changed, because the items in the list have been changed but the scroll state hasn't. I've tried to mitigate this issue with loadStates, but this was not enough. Any ideas?

Can you [edit] your question accordingly to make it more clear what the issue is?
